# SQL Server LINQ selectmany and orderby timeout

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

In SQL Server 2017 Express I have two level of master / details relations tables like this

```
CREATE TABLE ADHERANTS(
    [ID_ADHERANT] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
    [ADH_NOM] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ADH_PRENOM [varchar](50) NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE  INSCRIPTIONS(
    [ID_INSCRIPTION] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
    [INS_ID_ADHERANT] [int] NOT NULL /* foreign key for ADHERANTS*/,
    [INS_DATE_DEBUT] [date] NULL,
    [INS_DUREE] [int] NULL,
    [INS_DATE] [date] NULL
);

CREATE TABLE SEANCES(
    [ID_SEANCE] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
    [INS_ID_INSCRIPTION] [int] NULL /* foreign key for INSCRIPTIONS*/,
    [SEA_DEBUT] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [SEA_FIN] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [SEA_MANUAL] [int] NULL,
    [SEA_MONTANT] [decimal](14, 2) NULL,
    [SEA_NOM] [varchar](50) NULL,
 );
```

Please note that the foreign key in `SEANCEs` is nullable.

What I want is to get for each `ADHERANTS` the last detail record based on date.

In EF Core 3.1 LINQ I have something like this:

```
   var res = (from adh in _context.ADHERANTS
                        
                       .Include(x => x.Inscriptions)
                       .ThenInclude(x => x.Seances)
                       select new  
                       {

                           ID_ADHERANT = adh.ID_ADHERANT,
                           ADH_NOM = adh.ADH_NOM,
                           ADH_PRENOM = adh.ADH_PRENOM,
                          

                           LastInscription = (from nn in adh.Inscriptions.OrderByDescending(a => a.INS_DATE_DEBUT)

                                              select new LastInscription()
                                              {
                                                  Date = nn.INS_DATE_DEBUT,
                                                  Duree = nn.INS_DUREE.Value
                                              }).FirstOrDefault(),
                           
                           LastSeance = (from mm in adh.Inscriptions.SelectMany(a => a.Seances).OrderByDescending(a => a.SEA_DEBUT)
                                         select mm.SEA_DEBUT).FirstOrDefault()

                         });

  IncrementalItemsSource.LoadItems(res.Skip(baseIndex).Take(10));
```

Which works and produces this SQL query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [a].[ID_ADHERANT], [a].[ADH_NOM], [a].[ADH_PRENOM], [t0].[INS_DATE_DEBUT], [t0].[INS_DUREE], [t0].[c], (
    SELECT TOP(1) [s].[SEA_DEBUT]
    FROM [INSCRIPTIONS] AS [i]
    INNER JOIN [SEANCES] AS [s] ON [i].[ID_INSCRIPTION] = [s].[INS_ID_INSCRIPTION]
    WHERE [a].[ID_ADHERANT] = [i].[INS_ID_ADHERANT]
    ORDER BY [s].[SEA_DEBUT] DESC)
FROM [ADHERANTS] AS [a]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [t].[INS_DATE_DEBUT], [t].[INS_DUREE], [t].[c], [t].[ID_INSCRIPTION], [t].[INS_ID_ADHERANT]
    FROM (
        SELECT [i0].[INS_DATE_DEBUT], [i0].[INS_DUREE], 1 AS [c], [i0].[ID_INSCRIPTION], [i0].[INS_ID_ADHERANT], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [i0].[INS_ID_ADHERANT] ORDER BY [i0].[INS_DATE_DEBUT] DESC) AS [row]
        FROM [INSCRIPTIONS] AS [i0]
    ) AS [t]
    WHERE [t].[row] <= 1
) AS [t0] ON [a].[ID_ADHERANT] = [t0].[INS_ID_ADHERANT]
ORDER BY (SELECT 1) desc
OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_0 ROWS ONLY',N'@__p_0 int',@__p_0=10
```

But if I try to add an `orderby` on top of that I get a timeout exception:

```
   var res = (from adh in _context.ADHERANTS
                        
                       .Include(x => x.Inscriptions)
                       .ThenInclude(x => x.Seances)
                       select new  
                       {

                           ID_ADHERANT = adh.ID_ADHERANT,
                           ADH_NOM = adh.ADH_NOM,
                           ADH_PRENOM = adh.ADH_PRENOM,
                          

                           LastInscription = (from nn in adh.Inscriptions.OrderByDescending(a => a.INS_DATE_DEBUT)

                                              select new LastInscription()
                                              {
                                                  Date = nn.INS_DATE_DEBUT,
                                                  Duree = nn.INS_DUREE.Value
                                              }).FirstOrDefault(),
                           
                           LastSeance = (from mm in adh.Inscriptions.SelectMany(a => a.Seances).OrderByDescending(a => a.SEA_DEBUT)
                                         select mm.SEA_DEBUT).FirstOrDefault()

                         });
  res = res.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastInscription.Date);
  IncrementalItemsSource.LoadItems(res.Skip(baseIndex).Take(10));
```

As a workaround I have tried to modify the generated SQL query and put the order by there.

It worked for all the columns except for the `lastseance` one which take forever when executed.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [a].[ID_ADHERANT], [a].[ADH_NOM], [a].[ADH_PRENOM], [t0].[INS_DATE_DEBUT], [t0].[INS_DUREE], [t0].[c], (
    SELECT TOP(1) [s].[SEA_DEBUT]
    FROM [INSCRIPTIONS] AS [i]
    INNER JOIN [SEANCES] AS [s] ON [i].[ID_INSCRIPTION] = [s].[INS_ID_INSCRIPTION]
    WHERE [a].[ID_ADHERANT] = [i].[INS_ID_ADHERANT]
    ORDER BY [s].[SEA_DEBUT] DESC)
FROM [ADHERANTS] AS [a]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [t].[INS_DATE_DEBUT], [t].[INS_DUREE], [t].[c], [t].[ID_INSCRIPTION], [t].[INS_ID_ADHERANT]
    FROM (
        SELECT [i0].[INS_DATE_DEBUT], [i0].[INS_DUREE], 1 AS [c], [i0].[ID_INSCRIPTION], [i0].[INS_ID_ADHERANT], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [i0].[INS_ID_ADHERANT] ORDER BY [i0].[INS_DATE_DEBUT] DESC) AS [row]
        FROM [INSCRIPTIONS] AS [i0]
    ) AS [t]
    WHERE [t].[row] <= 1
) AS [t0] ON [a].[ID_ADHERANT] = [t0].[INS_ID_ADHERANT]
ORDER BY 7 desc /* order by the last seance*/
OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_0 ROWS ONLY',N'@__p_0 int',@__p_0=10
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your query in the following way, I think it will work faster.

```cs
var query = 
   from adh in _context.ADHERANTS
   from nn in adh.Inscriptions
      .OrderByDescending(a => a.INS_DATE_DEBUT)
      .Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
   from mm in nn.Seances
      .OrderByDescending(a => a.SEA_DEBUT)
      .Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()                                      
   select new  
   {

       ID_ADHERANT = adh.ID_ADHERANT,
       ADH_NOM = adh.ADH_NOM,
       ADH_PRENOM = adh.ADH_PRENOM,
                          
       LastInscription = new LastInscription
         {
             Date = nn.INS_DATE_DEBUT,
             Duree = nn.INS_DUREE.Value
         },                           
       LastSeance = mm.SEA_DEBUT
   };
```

Comment: I think `.DefaultIfEmpty()` isn't even necessary, but apart from that, yes, this looks a lot better, also when the final ordering is added.

Comment: @GertArnold, I think `DefaultIfEmpty` is necessary, because EF can translate `from` in INNER JOIN. Will check later and correct answer if EF do some assumptions in that case.

Comment: it seems that it work as expected and it's faster and much more readable :p thanks a lot <3

Comment: @GertArnold, as I expected. Without `.DefaultIfEmpty()`, EFC generates INNER JOIN, which may filter out top level records.